# Why can Oracle not select truthiness of a statement in the order by cluase

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

If I want to order a table by one column, but extract one specified row to the top, in MySQL, I can do something like this... ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/464f5/31))

```
select * from name
order by surname != 'moon', surname
```

However, when I want to do this in oracle, the truthy test in the order by clause does not work, and I end up having to do something like this... ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/464f5/41))

```
select surname from name 
order by case when surname = 'moon' then 0 else 1 end, surname
```

What is the reason for Oracle not supporting truthy tests in the order by clause?

(or even the select statement for that matter)

---

### Results

(all are in alphabetical order, except `moon` which has floated to top)

```
SURNAME
moon
adane
bell
day
larkin
williams
```

Comment: Just a side question - to sort on a boolean, you'd need to answer the question, which is higher: "True" or "False"? :)

Comment: Well, as a JavaScript man myself, I would say that false would be equal to exactly 0 and true would be equal to exactly 1. I think this is the reason oracle did not implement it, because implicit type coercion seems potentially less robust. I expect they prefer the explicit where clause to do the same thing in more versatile, and clearly defined way. Thanks @JeffreyKemp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I expect that the answer comes down to the fact that Oracle does not have a `boolean` data type in SQL (there is a boolean in PL/SQL).  The expression `a != b` would have to evaluate to a boolean and SQL would need to be able to deal with that as a first-class data type in order to do something like `ORDER BY` it or return it in the `SELECT` list.

The `case` statement you posted or the equivalent `DECODE` would likely be your best bet.  You could do something that would be gratuitous overkill here (but maybe not in the actual problem you're trying to solve) by creating a user-defined boolean type that implements methods to do things like sort the results and using that to evaluate your conditions.  But that's *way* more code than your `CASE` statement.

Comment: And it *probably* doesn't support Boolean because [it's optional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#SQL). The only ANSI platform that does implment boolean is PostgreSQL. Interestingly MySQL and MS Access both have boolean and we know what their SQL is like

Comment: Great answer - thanks, and thanks also to @ConradFrix who addresses the reason behind it.

Comment: dBase II for the IBM PC back in the 1980s supported boolean data types too!